# Native IPv6 on openwrt

Tags: ipv6, openwrt

I just flushed my linksys wrt54gl router with openwrt and was hoping to enable IPv6 connectivity, but I can't figure out how. Every tutorial I reed tells how to do it using e.g. tunnelbroker but I don't need a tunnel over IPv4 since I already have IPv6 into my house. When I SSH into the router I can run ping6 ipv6.google.com without a single problem, but I can't get it to work on my computer...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have got the connectivity part working, but you're actually not acting as a router.

You *must* find out the following from your ISP:

- Whether the subnet assigned to your ppp0 interface is the same one you use for your LAN
- How the subnet is delegated to you (static, DHCPv6, etc.)

[These WRT54G builds](http://wiki.andy.id.au/Home/openwrt/custom-builds) include DHCPv6-PD support, which works with [Internode](http://ipv6.internode.on.net/), an Australian ISP, but you have said you are from Norway, and your ISP does not necessarily do it the same way.

You have mentioned radvd, but that is pretty much irrelevant — you need to figure out what the subnets are before you go anywhere near something like radvd. `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` is a good start, but you still need more.

If you go to the [ADSL FAQ from Internode](http://ipv6.internode.on.net/configuration/adsl-faq-guide/), they provide this information:

> The IPv6 Broadband Trial allows
>   Internode customers to test and gain
>   experience with IPv6 using their
>   existing Internode ADSL service.
>
> **What will this give me?**
>
> - Your existing IPv4 address (if static) and route(s)
> - A dual-stack IPv4/IPv6
> - A dynamic /64 IPv6 prefix for your PPP session
> - A stable /60 IPv6 prefix for your LAN (if you are using a router with Prefix Delegation)
>
> **How do hosts on my LAN obtain globally routed IPv6 addresses?**
>
> Your IPv6 Access Device/router should assign /64 subnets to it's interfaces after it obtains a DHCPv6 PD lease. It should then offer the prefix to your hosts via IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration. In more complicated setups you may choose to use DHCPv6 as well.

You must find out the equivalent information from your ISP. I'd hazard a guess that you need something like a [DHCPv6-PD–enabled setup](http://wiki.andy.id.au/Home/openwrt/custom-builds), but we can't know for sure until we get more information. Heck, we don't even know *what* your ISP is.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand a bit more now. However, due to special circumstances contacting my isp is not possible given that I am on a school network. Aprisiate your answer though. Sorry slow reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up either DHCPD6 (not worth it for you unless you need integration with internal DNS) or radvd, which advertises IPv6 routes that the clients will pick up.  radvd is recommended.  Make sure you've got enough IPv6 addresses to go around and that your router is claming an address from a /64 or a /48.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not certain how to do this. I know how to install radvd, but not how to set it up (if any setup is necessary). Also I don't know how to make sure I've got enough IPv6-addresses or how to check if my router is claiming an address from a /64 or /48. All I know is that when I run ifconfig I get a line saying "inet6 addr: xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link".

Sorry but I'm really new to this, and if you could point me in the direction of what to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: See here: http://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=106.0